# Passing Arguments to Register-EngineEvent Action Scriptblock

Tags: powershell, events, event-handling

I want to catch a PowerShell script as it finishes so that I can do some final processing before it stops. `Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.Exiting` seems to be the way to do it but it does not work for anything other than trivial applications.

Simple examples work. For example:

```
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.Exiting -Action {write-host "This is trivial"}
```

will print "This is trivial" when the script finishes. However, any action block that needs data passed to it does not get that data. For example:

```
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.Exiting -Action {write-host ">> " $($event.MessageData)} -MessageData "This doesn't work"
```

will only print the two leading angle brackets and not the string "This doesn't work".

Note that I'm calling the script from a Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) and it is there that the `Write-Host` ultimately prints, after PowerShell has exited.

Furthermore, with the exception of the `$Event` automatic variables, all the others such as `$Sender`, `$Args`, `$EventArgs` etc. are not populated. Also some of the properties of `$Event` are not populated. For example, `$Event.ComputerName` prints nothing, but `$Event.TimeGenerated` prints the current date and time. My computer has a name.

I have included a tiny example program which demonstrates either that I am doing it wrong or that there is some limitation in what can be done with `Register-EngineEvent` maybe it is even a bug I suppose.

I have spent quite a lot of time searching web sites but I haven't found any examples where they are passing data to an action block for `Register-EngineEvent`.

```
sleep 1
write-host "Starting"
sleep 1
write-host "Finished"
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.Exiting -MessageData "This doesn't work" -Action {write-host ">> " $($event.MessageData)}
sleep 2
```

I would expect that little script to print "Starting" followed 1 second later by "Finished" and then, after a further 2 seconds the event handler to print 
">> This doesn't work". I do get the first two messages but all I get from the handler is ">>".

I am running on Windows 10 with Powershell V5. I am not running it in ISE. I use the command line `powershell -file .\try6.ps1` where `try6.ps1` is the script I've included above.

If anyone can suggest what I am doing wrong or alternative ways of doing this that would be great but even if it is just that it is a known bug or that I have misunderstood what `PowerShell.exiting` or `Register-EngineEvent` are and they can't be used in the way I am trying that would be very helpful as well.

Comment: So you're trying to `Write-host` back into the *same PS session* you're exiting from? I can't see how that is supposed to work. What if you write out your message data to file? If that works better, there's your problem.

Comment: @Trix: Colin is calling the PS script from `cmd.exe`, which is where the `Write-Host` output prints after the PS process exits - I've updated the question to make that clearer.

Comment: Yet another argument for abolishing CMD wrappers for PS scripts. As time goes on, I really don't get why people still do this.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: While this answer contains hopefully useful **background information**, it **does not solve the OP's problem** of wanting to pass custom event data to a `PowerShell.Exiting` event handler.

What Colin encountered is **apparently a *known bug***: see [GitHub issue #7000](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7000).

---

Generally, just to clarify: the `PowerShell.Exiting` event only fires on exiting a PowerShell *session*, not a *script run inside a session*.

Using it in the running session itself (as opposed to using it in a *remote* session that *forwards* the event to the caller) limits you to:

- taking behind-the-scenes action when the session ends
- using `Write-Host` to write output that the *calling* process potentially sees (use of implicit output or `Write-Output` is no longer an option, because PowerShell's output streams are no longer available at the time the event fires).

You're running a script locally via PowerShell's CLI, `powershell.exe` which means that the limitations above apply to you.

The automatic event-related variables documented in [about_Automatic_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) do not seem to contain much information when the event fires, as the following command demonstrates:

```sh
PS> powershell -c '$null = 
     Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.Exiting -Action {
      $Event, $EventSubscriber, $Sender, $EventArgs, $Args | Out-string | Write-Host 
     }'
ComputerName     :
RunspaceId       : 1a763430-5cd8-4b74-aaaf-7a90e514518d
EventIdentifier  : 1
Sender           :
SourceEventArgs  :
SourceArgs       : {}
SourceIdentifier : PowerShell.Exiting
TimeGenerated    : 3/26/19 12:15:48 AM
MessageData      :

SubscriptionId   : 1
SourceObject     :
EventName        :
SourceIdentifier : PowerShell.Exiting
Action           : System.Management.Automation.PSEventJob
HandlerDelegate  :
SupportEvent     : False
ForwardEvent     : False
```

- `$Event` exists, and provides the runspace ID and a time stamp reflecting the time of the event.

  - `$Event.ComputerName` is presumably only populated if the event was *forwarded* (via [`Register-EngineEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-engineevent)'s `-Forward` switch) from a different computer in the context of remoting; if the property is empty, the implication is that the event fired on the local machine.
- `$EventSubscriber` exists, but doesn't contain any useable information.
- `$EventArgs`, `$Sender` and `$Args` are not populated.

Given the above, you could streamline your output to only contain the time stamp of the event and the local computer name's name:

```sh
PS> powershell -c '
     $null = 
       Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.Exiting -Action {
       [pscustomobject] @{ TimeGenerated = $Event.TimeGenerated; ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME }| Format-List | Out-String | Write-Host 
     }
     # ... call your script 
     .\try6.ps1
   '


TimeGenerated : 3/26/2019 8:57:53 AM
ComputerName  : Workstation10
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice and especially for the link to the bug. I did wonder if it was by design since the programmer might argue that there is little point in populating the automatic variable as the session is ending but I see from the bug report that it isn't just for PowerShell.Exiting that this problem exists. Anyway, I have done what I actually wanted to do a different way and that is working fine so all is well.  Thanks also to @Trix for the suggestions. Strangely it does work. I did wonder if that was the problem too but it seems not.